# load a class in hook_install

Tags: 8, installation

In my custom module I have created a class in `mymod/src/Controller/TestClass.php`.

In hook_install I want to call a function of that class

```
function mymod_install() {
Drupal\mymod\TestClass::testfunction();
}
```

and the TestClass.php contains the following code

```
namespace Drupal\mymod
  class TestClass {
    public static function testfunction() {
     // do some stuff
    }
 }
```

But whe I try to enable the module It gives me the following error.

```
Error: Class 'Drupal\mymod\TestClass' not found in
/var/www/drupal8/modules/custom/mymod/mymod.install, line 16
```

Is the hook_install executes first from autoloading the class of this module?

How will I call that function from hook_install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class is here:

> mymod/src/Controller/TestClass.php

Then your namespace is wrong. It should be:

```
Drupal\mymod\Controller\TestClass::testfunction();
```

You'll also need to update the namespace in the class file itself:

```
namespace Drupal\mymod\Controller
```

Or, instead of making those changes, you could just move TestClass.php to mymod/src.